# If $\{n_k\}$ is the set of natural numbers with no 0 in their decimal expansion, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n_k}$ converges to a number less than 90

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, decimal-expansion

Let ${\{n_1,n_2,…\} }$
be the set of natural numbers that do not use the digit 0
in their decimal expansion. Then, the series
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n_k}$
converges to a number less than 90.

Is it ok to consider the series as  $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} - \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{10^i}$$

This is an exercise problem in "Mathematical analysis" by ${Tom.M.Apostol.}$  I didn't understand the proof given for a similar question in the site already.  I'm not good at permutations and combinations and inclusion and exclusion. Can anyone help with the proof with elementary calculations.

Comment: See this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/364658/1093844 also you are omitting numbers like $10,100, \cdots$ but there are other numbers with $0$ in it like $20,105$ etc

Comment: Note:  your decomposition doesn't make sense.  First of all, there are plenty of natural numbers like $10123$ that have a $0$ in their decimal expression but are not powers of $10$.  Secondly, the first of sums diverges and you can't generally rearrange series if they diverge.

Comment: The main reason that approach won't work is that the harmonic series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, so you would essentially get $\infty-\infty$ which is indeterminate. Note also that what you are subtracting is the reprocals of $\{10^i\}$, and this set excludes things like $20$, $501$, $23045$, etc.

Comment: It's better to tell us which is the similar question on the site, and what it is about that solution that you don't understand.